# Session array storing only one value when printing outside it's parental while loop

Tags: php, arrays, session, while-loop

I was making a follow unfollow system in which a the user's followings where stored in a session array. The session array works well inside it's parental while loop but shows only one item when printing in another file.

```
while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) { 
$_SESSION['followings'] = array();
$_SESSION['followings'][] = $row1['towigf'];


?>
<div> <p id="user_<?php echo $row1['follow_id']; ?>" style="margin-left: 3.5em; margin-top: 0em;"><?php echo $row1['towigf']; ?></p></div><button onclick="send_data(<?php echo $row1['user_no']; ?>)" style="float: right; margin-top: -2.5em;background: transparent; border: 1px solid #0099FF; color: #0099FF;" type="button" name="follow" id="follow_<?php echo $row1['user_no']; ?>" style="float: right; margin-top: -3em; margin-right: 1em;">Follow</button></div>
    
   <?php //everything good here 
    echo $_SESSION['followings']; ?>
    
    <?php }} ?>
    
    <?php
    // Not working here
    echo $_SESSION['followings'];
    ?>
```

Comment: `$_SESSION['followings'] = array();` - you reinitialize it as an empty array inside the loop.

Comment: And `echo`ing an array will never work.